# How can you convert a credit score into a number between 0 and 100?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Credit scores are numbers between 350 and 850.

Lets say someone's score is 600

How can you determine what that score of 600 would be if it was measured from 0 to 100 rather than the range 350 to 850?

Interested to know what the relative differences are between scores which to my mind is easier represented in a 0 to 100 range than the intentionally obscure method that is the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First subtract $350$, so that the number range is changed from $350-850$ to $0-500$.

Then divide by $5$, so that the range changes from $0-500$ to $0-100$.

So $600$ becomes $(600-350)/5=250/5=50$ on the scale of $0$ to $100$.

If you insist on using $1-100$ instead of $0-100$ then things get a bit uglier as you would have to subtract $350$, then multiply by $99/500$ and finally add $1$.

Comment: Oh thank you i’ve updated the question to be 0 to 100 that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

$$850-350=500\\850-600=250$$ So a score of $600$ is the equivalent of $250$ over a possible range of $500$.

Thus, $50$ in a range of $0-100$..

Answer (score 1):

To find the map, we may build this triangle, and actually it's a map, which maps $[350,850]$ to $[0,100]$(as the figure shows). 
With a simple geometrical analysis, we can get the answer. Assume the credit score is $x$, and the converted score is $y$, then the convert equation is $\frac{x-350}{850-350}=\frac{y-0}{100-0}$, then $y=\frac{1}{5}x-70$
[image: 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IH9M.png]